# How to calculate ratio of values in a pandas dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to pandas and decided to learn it by playing around with some data I pulled from my favorite game's API.  I have a dataframe with two columns "playerId" and "winner" like so:

```
playerStatus:
______________________
   playerId   winner
0    1848      True
1    1988      False
2    3543      True
3    1848      False
4    1988      False
...
```

Each row represents a match the player participated in.  My goal is to either transform this dataframe or create a new one such that the win percentage for each playerId is calculated.  For example, the above dataframe would become:

```
playerWinsAndTotals
_________________________________________
   playerId   wins  totalPlayed   winPct
0    1848      1        2         50.0000
1    1988      0        2         0.0000
2    3543      1        1         100.0000
...
```

It took quite a while of reading pandas docs, but I actually managed to achieve this by essentially creating two different tables (one to find the number of wins for each player, one to find the total games for each player), and merging them, then taking the ratio of wins to games played.

Creating the "wins" dataframe:

```
temp_df = playerStatus[['playerId', 'winner']].value_counts().reset_index(name='wins')
onlyWins = temp_df[temp_df['winner'] == True][['playerId', 'wins']]
onlyWins
_________________________
    playerId    wins
1     1670       483
3     1748       474
4     2179       468
6     4006       434
8     1668       392
...
```

Creating the "totals" dataframe:

```
totalPlayed = playerStatus['playerId'].value_counts().reset_index(name='totalCount').rename(columns={'index': 'playerId'})
totalPlayed
____________________

   playerId   totalCount
0    1670        961
1    1748        919
2    1872        877
3    4006        839
4    2179        837
...
```

Finally, merging them and adding the "winPct" column.

```
playerWinsAndTotals = onlyWins.merge(totalPlayed, on='playerId', how='left')
playerWinsAndTotals['winPct'] = playerWinsAndTotals['wins']/playerWinsAndTotals['totalCount'] * 100
playerWinsAndTotals
_____________________________________________

   playerId   wins   totalCount     winPct
0    1670      483      961       50.260146
1    1748      474      919       51.577802
2    2179      468      837       55.913978
3    4006      434      839       51.728248
4    1668      392      712       55.056180
...
```

Now, the reason I am posting this here is because I know I'm not taking full advantage of what pandas has to offer.  Creating and merging two different dataframes just to find the ratio of player wins seems unnecessary.  I feel like I took the "scenic" route on this one.

To anyone more experienced than me, how would you tackle this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can take advantage of the way that Boolean values are handled mathematically (`True` being `1` and `False` being `0`) and use 3 aggregation functions `sum`, `count` and `mean` per group ([`groupby aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html)). We can also take advantage of [Named Aggregation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation) to both create and rename the columns in one step:

```
df = (
    df.groupby('playerId', as_index=False)
        .agg(wins=('winner', 'sum'),
             totalCount=('winner', 'count'),
             winPct=('winner', 'mean'))
)
# Scale up winPct
df['winPct'] *= 100
```

`df`:

```
   playerId  wins  totalCount  winPct
0      1848     1           2    50.0
1      1988     0           2     0.0
2      3543     1           1   100.0
```

---

DataFrame and imports:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'playerId': [1848, 1988, 3543, 1848, 1988],
    'winner': [True, False, True, False, False]
})
```

Comment: Great answer, this also answered my question about the booleans being treated as 1s and 0s.

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

# If for any reason winner column is a string and not a boolean try
# import numpy as np
# df['winner'] = np.where(df['winner'] == 'True', 1, 0)

df = df.groupby('playerId')['winner'].agg(['count', 'sum'])
df['percentage'] = 100 * df['sum'] / df['count']
df = df.rename(columns={'count': 'total', 'sum': 'wins'})
print(df)
```

prints

```
          total  wins  percentage
playerId                   
1848          2     1        50.0
1988          2     0         0.0
3543          1     1       100.0
```

Data I used

```
playerId,winner
1848,True
1988,False
3543,True
1848,False
1988,False
```

Comment: Much more succinct, tyvm.  Quick question, why is the sum aggregation only adding up the rows with `True` in the winner column?  Is it because it is treating booleans as 1s and 0s?

Comment: Yes in python True + True + False = 2, this is why I have a comment about True being a string and not a boolean.

Comment: Ah, I glossed right over the comment the first time I read it.  Thanks for clearing that up!

Answer (score 3):

In your case just do `mean` can yield the pct

```
out = df.groupby('playerId')['winner'].agg(['sum','count','mean'])
Out[22]: 
          sum  count  mean
playerId                  
1848        1      2   0.5
1988        0      2   0.0
3543        1      1   1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'playerId': {0: 1848, 1: 1988, 2: 3543, 3: 1848, 4: 1988},
 'winner': {0: True, 1: False, 2: True, 3: False, 4: False}})

s = df.groupby('playerId')['winner'].apply(lambda x: (np.sum(x)/len(x)*100))

df = (df.groupby('playerId')
.agg({'playerId':'count', 'winner': 'sum'})
.rename(columns={'winner':'wins','playerId':'totalPlayed'})

.reset_index()
)

df['winPct'] = df['playerId'].map(s)

df = df[['playerId', 'wins', 'totalPlayed', 'winPct']]

print(df)

   playerId  wins  totalPlayed  winPct
0      1848     1            2    50.0
1      1988     0            2     0.0
2      3543     1            1   100.0
```